# Timewarp in the comment time

Tags: support, comments, timestamps

This is not a huge issue (not huge at all), but I first noticed this maybe a couple of weeks ago and it's time I mentioned it. The timestamp commentary on comments is saying *minutes* when it should be saying *seconds*.

In the example below, it said `8 mins ago` the moment I posted the comment, I then immediately edited it twice, this is what it says:

[image]

Note that it would have been a maximum of 60 seconds between when I first posted the question the the second of the edits - certainly nowhere near 9 minutes. I may be a retarded typist (2 edits), but I'm certainly not slow.

Comment: Hmm.. let's see... looks fine to me. Any chance you messed with your computer's time?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Coincidentally my machine's clock is..... 9 minutes fast. Obviously the script does an abs() on the time diff so that a negative time doesn't get shown. Problem solved. Post it as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: If your clock is 9 minutes fast, then the time diff is in fact positive -- comment posting date is 10 o'clock, your clock is 10:09, and thus the comment was posted 9 minutes ago.

Comment: @balpha See - I told you I was a retarded typist :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No worry dear friends, this is NOT a [rip in the space-time continuum](http://angleofreflection.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/scientists-detect-rip-in-space-time-continuum/).

The HTML for the element containing the "... ago" for comments and posts:

```
<span title="2013-01-24 10:11:54Z" class="relativetime-clean">
```

Then there is clever jQuery code iterating all elements with that class and then with each:

```javascript
d = d.substr(0, 10) + "T" + d.substr(11, 10);
d = new Date(d);
d = ((new Date).getTime() - d.getTime()) / 1E3;
var c = Math.floor(d / 86400);
d = isNaN(c) || 0 > c || 31 <= c ? void 0: 0 == c && (2 > d && "just now" || 60 > d && Math.floor(d) + (u ? "s ago": " secs ago") || 120 > d && (u ? "1m ago": "1 min ago") || 3600 > d && Math.floor(d / 60) + (u ? "m ago": " mins ago") || 7200 > d && (u ? "1h ago": "1 hour ago") || 86400 > d && Math.floor(d / 3600) + (u ? "h ago": " hours ago"))
```

Where `d` is initially given the value of the span title.

As you see (or can't see if JavaScript is alien to you), the time difference is based **on the local machine time**, so when that time is off so will be the timestamp displayed.

Don't mess with the <strike>Zohan</strike> computer time!