# Comment on an answer before it existed

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits, timestamps

I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20000023/851811) on the "New answers to old questions" list, and looking at the comment I was shocked to see it was coming... from the past!

[image]

Is this a bug?

**EDIT**: Summarizing what's been discussed in the comments below, and looking at the post's [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20000023/revisions) it seems the answer was really posted on 2013-11-15, it got the comment and also was deleted the same day.

[image]

So the bug seems to be in the answer, not in the comment. Looks like something happened to it to make it appear as if it was answered today (2013-12-13 03:01:30Z). Whatever happened did not reflect in the post revisions page.

Also, as Wooble said in his [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211413/comment-on-an-answer-before-it-existed#comment679540_211413), the original delete votes seemed to be still active on the post.

**EDIT 2**: In addition to a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20187420/revisions) [more](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20468038/revisions) cases as Flexo♦ pointed out in his comments, there is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20633838/851811), which was flagged as spam and deleted 3 hours ago (2013-12-17 13:55:59Z), and got an approved suggested edit a couple of hours *later* (2013-12-17 15:31:07Z). It seems this made the post *ressurect*.

[image]

Comment: Time travel is a 10k privilege

Comment: The really strange thing is that [stewbob](http://stackoverflow.com/users/107899/stewbob) hasn't even been on stack overflow since that answer was posted. And nor has [alexf1980](http://stackoverflow.com/users/572634/alexf1980) who posted the "answer"

Comment: at Tavern, they once discussed [time traveling](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1650632#1650632) "I could handle flags before they were flagged... I'd be banned for failed audits I didn't even see yet... suspended for voting irregularities committed next week..." etc. Someone apparently _really_ managed to get to the future and comment _before_ the post was submitted

Comment: Curiously, looking at it's [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20000023/revisions), it was posted and deleted on Nov 15. No revision about undelete.

Comment: According to [stewbob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898901/revision-control-of-data-inside-lightswitch/20000023?noredirect=1#comment30760747_20000023) they really did post the comment a long time ago, so it must be the answer timestamp that is wrong

Comment: Presumably it was undeleted at the time it's shown as being posted, although the revisions not showing the undelete is *another* bug.

Comment: Now the answer is gone again.. Which makes me wonder..

Comment: The bug seems to be on the answer's timestamp indeed. What @Wooble said below makes sense, not sure why would anyone want to undelete that answer though.

Comment: I was actually able to delete it with a *single* new delete vote, because the other 2 were still on the question.

Comment: So much for my request yesterday to burninate the [future] tag...

Comment: There was a review audit at about 05:01:43 yesterday on the post which is almost exactly 2 hours after the post was allegedly made. This makes me think the one of two things happened: a) the audit forked reality and re-wrote history by somehow superimposing itself on the true universe or b) The audit awoke the sleeping corpse of the undead post. (Also I wonder if all audit post timestamps are set as now -2 hours)

Comment: Happened again: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20187420/revisions - based around a failed audit again too

Comment: And again: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20468038/revisions - there was a failed audit in the mix again too.

Comment: @Flexo This could be another one: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20633838/revisions. This answer was flagged as spam (flag deemed helpful), and now it has resurrected with a suggested edit. Someone somehow was able to suggest an edit to a deleted post (not only deleted but also flagged as spam).

Comment: possible dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164845/timewarp-in-the-comment-time

Comment: @n00b pretty sure it isn't - this is out by weeks not months and there are multiple separate delete events

Comment: @XaviLópez yet again that's had a late answers review audit failed on the post

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Shog brought [this question's revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20189905/revisions) (10K only) to our attention today and I immediately said "LINQ2SQL".

Turns out that /review wasn't loading audit posts detached from the current [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so any changes to its properties (audit posts have most visible properties altered) are tracked and an errant [SubmitChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) could persist invalid data.

In these specific cases, that errant SubmitChanges occurred when a user failed an audit and had a UserHistory record recorded of the failure.  It only recently started happening (i.e. 5 days ago) when completing a review, because a change was made to validate the audit task server-side - this validation loaded the audit post and overwrote its properties.

I'm pushing the fix out right now and because a post's creation date is backed by separate history records, we can fix the fudged data.

<sub>On my "one day todo.txt", I have "burninate SubmitChanges calls".</sub>

Comment: CreationDate data has been fixed for the 23 affected posts.

Comment: Excellent! Also thanks for the details, this is one of the many reasons I love SO :-) I'm more a Java guy so don't know about LINQ2SQL but I could definitely see that happening with JPA/Hibernate too.

Comment: Any reason why this isn't tagged [tag:status-completed]?