# Why did this mysterious answer require another user's vote when a moderator already voted to delete that answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, moderation, vote-to-delete

See [this mysterious answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20000023/1369235). It was deleted by three users including a moderator. AFAIK, a moderator's vote is a binding vote, so no other vote is required to delete. But this answer's deletion status is something like this:

> deleted by kleopatra, Flexo♦, Wooble 20 hours ago

Has Flexo lost some power? Or, does [the mystery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211413/comment-on-an-answer-before-it-existed#comment679443_211413) of this answer continue?

Comment: Maybe they voted at exactly the same time and the order is random, or by name?

Comment: @Ben - If this is the case, we need to set a condition for it: if one of them is mod then keep him as a last voter.

Comment: Weird, I've deleted it twice according to [the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/admin/posts/timeline/20000023).

Comment: @Flexo you mean [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20000023/revisions), timeline doesn't show delete events as far as I know, plus not accessible to users (even 10K) on deleted posts. :/

Comment: Looks like the answer was somehow undeleted (although it's not showing anywhere) so when Wooble cast a single delete vote, the two previous delete votes were still there so that single vote triggered delete again. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Flexo linked to the mod-only timeline which is completely different from the older timeline that is accessible to users.

Comment: The answer is likely going to be the same as the answer to [that bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211413/comment-on-an-answer-before-it-existed). Something wonky definitely happened with that answer, and the issues are likely very related to each other.