# Answer before question in comments

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

*It is not about the order of post and comment, as in [Comment on an answer before it existed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211413/comment-on-an-answer-before-it-existed).*

After one [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21727310/715269) the comments 2 and 3 have changed their places. I started to write a comment answer, and while I did it, the author of the previous comment edited it. **So, we have answer before the question. The second comment was written as an answer to the third one.**

And younger comment goes before the older one (but that is not a problem, merely it is funny)

Edit: I'll try to explain it once more.

The third comment A appeared as the second one. Reading it, I wrote an answer B. At this time the author of A edited its content. When I saved the comment B, the comment A disappeared and B appeared as a second one. In a second the A appeared again, as the third one. It is obviously not correct. Comments should appear according to their first posting, not their editing.

Edit:
Ok, so, it seems, comment A was deleted and rewritten. Thank you.

Comment: Is this an effect of editing to make it look that way,  or were the comments physically misordered?

Comment: Sorry, can't figure what is the bug? The comments appear just fine, in chronological order as they should be.

Comment: They are misordered. The second comment was written as an answer to the third one.

Comment: So you probably guessed his intention and wrote it before he asked.... what's the bug? To make it right again, copy the comment contents to clipboard, delete the comment and post new same comment. Then delete the other two if you like, possibly re-adding them below.

Comment: Perhaps the other user copied the text, deleted, re-posted with a correction? I've done that myself. Err.... like @ShadowWizard has suggested you do whilst I was typing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments are displayed in the correct order as illustrated below.

[image]

The content of the comments indicates otherwise, likely due to side-channel communication, perhaps from one of the 500 comments posted (and possibly deleted) on the site between when the first comment was posted and the "third", as per @BillWoodger.

Comment: The third comment A appeared as the second one. Reading it, I wrote an answer B. At this time the author of A edited its content. When I saved the comment B, the comment A disappeared and B appeared as a second one. In a second the A appeared again, as the third one. It is obviously not correct. Comments should appear according to their first posting, not their editing.

Comment: @Gangnus they are. The other user most likely deleted the comment and re-posted it. Why won't you ask him?

Comment: How did you got that nice picture, please?

Comment: @Gangnus this is Google Chrome with web developer tools (right click something, inspect element) then a screenshot and then edit the screenshot with Preview.app